# Water pump query

Tags: plumbing, pump

I have just installed this water pump (260W) to the cold water pipe between my kitchen sink and outside tap in order to boost the water pressure to the outside tap as my water irrigation system is only getting a trickle of water out of it toward the end of the pipe:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00L90478Q/ref=od_aui_detailpages00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

The pump automatically turns on when it detects flow through it. i.e. when I turn my outside tap on you can hear the pump activate. However, the water pressure doesn't change at all when the pump has been activated. Of course it could be faulty, but as it's brand new and sounds like it's working I'm not so sure. I might just be missing something. Is my water pressure already high enough for the pump and therefore it is making no difference? Or is there something else I'm missing? I'm not sure. Any pointers appreciated.

Pump specs:

```
Q.Max 30L/min, 
Q. 20L/Min
H Max 15m
Power: 260W
Speed: 2860R/Min, IP44
```

I bought a water pressure gauge and tested it today:

Without the pump my outdoor tap has pressure of 50psi / 3.4 bar
With the pump it has a pressure of 80psi / 4.5 bar.
Therefore it is obviously working, so why does my hose pipe / irrigation system not perform any better? I would have though a pressure increase of 1.1 bar would have seen some performance increase. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you used a pressure gauge?  Perhaps the irrigation problem is pipe size or partially blocked?

Comment: What are the specs, size, model number etc. of the pump of the pump. What size piping is involved and what is the water pressure in the house.

Comment: I have updated the question with pump details / water pressure details.
The piping I use for my irrigation system is 4/6mm.
This is the system: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07BVR45FB/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: How did you make the pressure measurements?  Is it at the outdoor tap, with water flowing through the irrigation system in both cases?

Comment: No I attached this gauge directly to the outdoor tap: 
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Silverline-482913-Mains-Water-Pressure/dp/B06XY8WPYS

There was no way to attach it to the end of the irrigation system.

Comment: @nutman - Sorry, I guess I wasn’t clear.  I understand that you measured the pressure at the outdoor tap, but was water running through the system when you measured it?  Or did you disconnect the irrigation system and measure the pressure with no water flowing?

Comment: @Mark thanks for the reply it gave me an idea. I have a outdoor tap splitter so instead of connecting the water gauge directly to the outdoor tap, I allowed the irrigation system to run out of one side of the splitter, whilst attaching the gauge to the other. With the pump off and the irrigation system running, the pressure out of the other tap was 3 bar / 44 psi. With the pump on it was 4.4 bar / 66 psi so pressure is obviously being increased. I reckon regardless of the pump you can only get so much water through a 4mm pipe per second, so adding the pump makes no difference. Do you agree?

Comment: @nutman yes, I agree.  I didn’t realize it was 4 mm pipe.  That’s too small to get much flow through, and you’d have to increase the pressure far more than that to make much difference.  I agree with some of the earlier comments that the system is just too restricted.  You’ll need larger pipe to get more flow.